# A Reference From Andrej Bauer's Recent Talk on Countable Reals

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

Andrej Bauer gave a talk today in the topos institute colloquium (video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CBFUojXoq4)) announcing a proof that the dedekind reals can be countable in the absence of [LEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) and [CC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice).

At roughly the 27 minute mark, he mentions a "nice constructive news post" by Ingo Blechschmidt in which he reviews "all the ways that don't work". This question, then, is twofold:

First, is there a link to this note somewhere? I would love to read it, but after some cursory googling I haven't been able to find it.

Second, and relatedly, is there an actual "constructive news" website where this note was posted? I know that a lot of discussions happen in Zulip chats, and I wouldn't be surprised to learn that this note was posted in one of those. It would be nice if there were a slightly more "traditional" place where new updates in constructive mathematics were posted, but again, some cursory googling hasn't brought anything up.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the particularly soft question! ^_^

Comment: Ulrik Buchholtz just sent me [a link](https://groups.google.com/g/constructivenews/c/jSvzqu1LUis) to the post in question, which you can find in the "constructive news" google group on June 10, 2018. I'll leave this question open in case Ulrik wants to post here as well, or in case other people have things to say. In a day or two I'll add this as an answer and accept it to get this out of the open queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructive news google group doesn’t appear in Google search results, it seems. The post was from June 10, 2018, and is available at this link: https://groups.google.com/g/constructivenews/c/jSvzqu1LUis